# How to use implicit conversion in the same scope they are defined

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I need to check some non-trivial type evidence in a method, and implicits could do the work. It looks like that:

```
trait Cunning[T] {
  private[this] trait Path[U] extends Function[U,T]
  private[this] implicit def route1 : Path[List[T]] = ...
  private[this] implicit def route2 : Path[List[(T,T)]] = ...
  def apply[U](arg : U)(implicit path : Path[U]) : T = path(arg)
}
```

What I want is to invoke this method without additional imports:

```
val cunning : Cunning[Int] = ....
val out = cunning(List(1,2,3))
```

That would obviously fail, because all needed implicit conversions lies inside the cunning object and I should import them before usage. It bothers.

I'd like to modify cunning definition somehow, so implicit usage would not escape its scope and would require zero imports from user. Could you suggest me some trick to do so?

Comment: Could you overload the apply method with a dummy one (without an implicit param list) which just calls your main apply method?

Comment: I tried to create object and call apply method on it, but still it requires global visibility for implicit conversions

Comment: No, you will need to create two apply methods. One of them just delegates to the apply method having implicit params. So, all your implicit use is hidden inside your class/object only.

Comment: That would give "could not find implicit value for parameter path"